# Can I get back info like: "hover location", "Brush location" or "click location"

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I want to set up an interactive graph with shiny and plotly. 
Shiny has a build in feature to get info about the user interaction. Like: *input$plot_click*, *input$plot_dblclick*, *input$plot_hover* and *input$plot_brush*.
See:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html

Is there any option to get this over the Plotly API? Or can the API just handle one direction?

Plotly is really cool. Would love to use it in my shiny apps.

Thanks and best regards

Nico

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are click and hover bindings to Plotly graphs through the postMessage API:
https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API

A sketch of how to use the postMessage API with Shiny is here:
http://moderndata.plot.ly/dashboards-in-r-with-shiny-plotly/

And the code is here:
https://github.com/chriddyp/plotly-shiny

Comment: Ok give me some time to read through. I was a little bit fast in marking the question as answered. Thanks and best regards, Nico

Comment: Ok, I could not solve the problem with one of the two last link. But the first link has something like: "task: listen - specify a callback for a single event or group of events (zoom, hover, or click)" - but I could not figure it out how to use this in R properly. I think I would need to recode some parts in JS to get it done. Am I right? Thanks and best regards Nico

Answer (score 2):

There is now an `event_data` function from the `plotly` package itself that handles hovers, clicks, brushing etc.

There is a Shiny demo in the package that describes the usage:

```
library(plotly)
shiny::runApp(system.file("examples", "plotlyEvents", package = "plotly"))
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("plotType", "Plot Type:", choices = c("ggplotly", "plotly")),
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("hover"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brush"),
  verbatimTextOutput("zoom")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
        geom_point()
      ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = mpg, y = wt, key = key, mode = "markers") %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select")
    }
  })

  output$hover <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover events appear here (unhover to clear)" else d
  })

  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })

  output$brush <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click and drag events (i.e., select/lasso) appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })

  output$zoom <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
    if (is.null(d)) "Relayout (i.e., zoom) events appear here" else d
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(display.mode = "showcase"))
```

They also have examples of linked brushing and clicks on their main GitHub page:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly

Comment: If multiple plotly charts, use `source` to call individual plot. See [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/plotly/html/event_data.html).