# Plotly with R Shiny - Client To Server Communication

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'd like to use plotly in a shiny app but I need information about the plot interaction back in R. Is there any way to get plotly to send the information / coordinates from the hover, brush, etc. back to R?

There is an earlier question - [Can I get back info like: "hover location", "Brush location" or "click location"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592682/can-i-get-back-info-like-hover-location-brush-location-or-click-location) but this API seems useful for client side interaction. I have a feeling that `onInputChange` from shiny might help me achieve this but it would probably need me to do some javascript coding which I'm not good at (simple existing examples of this are also welcome). If there's a pure R+Shiny approach then that would be the best.

Comment: This should now be possible using the `event_data()` function